# Dynamically changing thread count in soapui

Tags: soapui, load-testing

Is there a way in SOAPUI(free version) to start my loadtest with 100 threads/vusers then increase the load by 25 threads every 10 minutes until the total number of threads reach 500

I appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Victor Hocke.

Comment: Have youo tried using the thread strategy? It gives a starting and a final thread count only, without the quantum as you wish to have.

Comment: yep but I don't get the desired result

Comment: I think I need the Grid strategy but unfortunately that's only on PRO version, I was hoping to have some setting on free version that would let me create the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

use the strategy "Thread", it will be ok.